# Rails micropost_controller @feed_item

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I was wondering what this line does exactly?

```
  @feed_items = []
```

It's from my micropost_controller create method

```
def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

If you need to know any other files let me know! thanks!

Comment: It just passing an `empty array` to `@feed_items`

Comment: Ok so this method, will build a micropost, flash a msg, and pass it to the empty feed_item array everytime??

Comment: No.If the `@micropost` is not saved then the empty array is passed to `@feed_items`.

Comment: Ok I understand.. But can I ask you sir, do you know what the benefit is of passing the empty array into feed_items if the save is not successful?

Comment: Its hard to tell.It depends on how the `@feed_items` is used later in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@feed_items** is used for dynamically show microposts in homepage

in /_feed.html.erb

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
<%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
 </ol>
 <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

and if save faild

```
@feed_items = []

> @feed_items.any?
=> false
```

so in /home.html.erb

```
<div class="span8">
  <h3>Micropost Feed</h3>
  <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
</div>
```

would not show faild one

Comment: Thanks now I understand it more deeply!